# PostGIS 2.0 ST_Transform with Rasters cannot find custom SRID

Tags: postgis, raster, coordinate-system, srid, postgis-2.0

I'm trying to calculate an average value in a buffer around a point.

Given a raster in EPSG 4326 and a similar point, this is fine, except that the values will be skewed as they are not projected in an equal-areas projection.

So - I've added to my spatial_ref_sys the SRID '97099' from saptialreference.org:
http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7099/

This works fine for transforming points [ **edit** - added example ]:

```sql
-- get all the diff areas of diff pix values in one tile in which a point lies
SELECT ST_Area((ST_DumpAsPolygons(r.rast)).geom),
       (ST_DumpAsPolygons(r.rast)).val,
       r.rid
FROM rasters AS r
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-2, 51), 4326), 97099) as pt
) AS p
ON ST_Intersects(r.rast, p.pt) AND r.filename = 'someraster.tif';
```

But using it with the raster fails with an error saying it cannot find SRID 97099 in spatial_ref_sys: [ **edit** - added error message ]

```
ERROR: rtpg_getSR: Cannot find SRID (97099) in spatial_ref_sys
SQL state: XX000
Context: SQL function "st_transform" statement 1
```

A `SELECT ... WHERE SRID = 97099` confirms it is there... So I'm a bit lost. Is it querying from somewhere else, or maybe ignoring anything that isn't EPSG? I've followed the example here, for rasters:
http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/RT_ST_Transform.html

Here's the full test SQL, the commented out lines show what I want to do, and the line above them will actually work (but is wrong, as it will still be 4326)

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_points;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_points ("gid" int, "point" geometry);
INSERT INTO tmp_points ("gid", "point") VALUES
  (100231, ST_MakePoint(172.3, -43.76667)),
  (100233, ST_MakePoint(171.71667, -43.91667)), 
  (100246, ST_MakePoint(170.92009, -44.09834)), 
  (100290, ST_MakePoint(170.95009, -44.44835)),
  (100497, ST_MakePoint(173.28271, -42.77409)), 
  (100498, ST_MakePoint(171.90983, -43.9236)),
  (1, ST_MakePoint(-2.136154, 49.220288))   
;


-- get the average value arount a point for a given radius
-- 
SELECT
  gid,
  filename,
  lon,
  lat,
  CAST(SUM(ST_Area((foo.gv).geom)*(foo.gv).val)/SUM(ST_Area((foo.gv).geom)) AS decimal(9,7)) AS avgimr,
  COUNT(foo.gv) as parts
FROM (
  SELECT
  ST_X(p.point)::NUMERIC(9, 5) AS lon, 
  ST_Y(p.point)::NUMERIC(9, 5) AS lat,
  p.gid,
  sn.filename,
  ST_Intersection(
    sn.rast,
    -- THIS COMMENTED LINE BELOW FAILS, THE ABOVE WORKS (is wrong)
    -- ST_Transform(sn.rast, 97099, 'Bilinear'),
    ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(p.point, 4326), 97099), 25000)
  ) AS gv
  FROM rasters sn, tmp_points p
  WHERE ST_Intersects(
    ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(p.point, 4326), 97099), 25000),
    sn.rast
    -- THIS COMMENTED LINE BELOW FAILS, THE ABOVE WORKS (is wrong)
    -- ST_Transform(sn.rast, 97099, 'Bilinear')
  )
  AND sn.filename = 'someraster.tif'
) AS foo
WHERE (foo.gv).val >= 0 AND (foo.gv).val <= 10
GROUP BY filename, gid, lon, lat
ORDER BY filename, gid, lon, lat;
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Postgis 2.0.0 source, it seems the raster version of `ST_Transform` is only checking projections where the `auth_name` is 'EPSG'. See line ~512 in `raster/rt_pg/rt_pg.c`:

```c
snprintf(sql, len, "SELECT CASE WHEN upper(auth_name) = 'EPSG' AND 
length(auth_srid::text) > 0 THEN upper(auth_name) || ':' || auth_srid ELSE '' END,
proj4text, srtext FROM spatial_ref_sys WHERE srid = %d LIMIT 1", srid);
```

See the source here: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/changeset/9787/trunk/raster/rt_pg/rt_pg.c

I'm not sure why it's limiting to EPSG, but it might be a bug worth filing on the project.

Comment: That is the correct reason, but in changing the auth_name and auth_srid to EPSG and 97099 respectively, the query now just blows up and disconnects from the DB without an error... :-(

Comment: For reference: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1862

Comment: This is (will be) fixed in PostGIS 2.0.1: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1782